# TensorFlow - IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tflearn

I was walking through [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/), and tried to evaluate the model as follows:

```
model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
```

I however get the following error:

```
return [x[start] for x in X]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

Why is that? How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

This is the size of my test data:

```
test_x: (36, 9, 6, 1)
test_y: (36, 2)
```

Would that be an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What tutorial is this from?

Comment: @sacul Thanks for your comment, good catch. I have added the link to the tutorial now :-)